# divisibility proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

For all integers $a$, there exists an integer $b$ such that $3$ divides $a+b$ and $3$ divides $2a+b$.

I think it is false and the negation will be: There exists an integer $a$ such that for all integers $b$, $3$ does not divide $a+b$ or $3$ doesn't divide $2a+b$.
How can I choose a to prove the negation?

Comment: Hint: if $3 \mid a+b$ and $3 \mid 2a+b$ then $3 \mid (2a+b)-(a+b)=a\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=1$, if $3$ divides $1+b$ and $3$ divides $2+b$.

Then $3$ must divide $2+b-(1+b)=1$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=1$. Suppose that there exists such $b$. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

More generally, let's work in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$. Denote the congruence classes of $a$ and $b$, $\bar a$ and $\bar b$.  The system can be written
$$\begin{cases}\phantom{-}\bar{a} +\bar b=\bar 0\\-\bar a+\bar b=0\end{cases},$$
and the only solutions are $\;\bar{a}=\bar b=\bar 0$.

This implies the given system has solutions in $b$ if and only if $a$ is divisible by $3$.